# Laravel 5.4: How do I redirect back to correct page when I have 3 post pages using the same url?

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-5

I want to keep the same url across 3 pages that have POST forms.
When a form fails validation i'm doing `\Redirect::back()->withErrors()` but if i'm on the second page it's returning to the 1st page. How can I return to the 2nd page instead of the 1st?

My routes are:

```
Route::post("/test",['as'=>'test','uses'=>'TestController@post']);
Route::get("/test",function(){ return View::make("pages.test"); });
```

My controller is:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{

function post(Request $request){
    if($request->has("test1")){
        return view('/pages/test2');
    }elseif($request->has("test2")){
        return \Redirect::back()->withErrors(["my error"]);
    }else{
        return "unknown test";
    }
}

}
```

My blade files are test.blade.php:

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => ['TestController@post']]) }}
Test1
{{ Form::hidden('test1', "test1")}}
{{ Form::submit('CONTINUE')}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

test2.blade.php :

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => ['TestController@post']]) }}
test2
{{ Form::hidden('test2', "test2") }}
{{ Form::submit('CONTINUE')}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

When `return \Redirect::back()->withErrors(["my error"]);` executes i'm expecting to return to test2.blade.php but i'm returning to test.blade.php. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `return view()` inside a `post` request.

This is an example of a request cycle from a shop:

```
GET  - show view 1 (shopping-cart)

POST - it's a form submmited from view 1
     - if it fails, it redirect to view 1
     - after doing the app logic, it redirects to view 2

GET  - show view 2 (payment-method)

POST - it's a form submmited from view 2
     - if it fails, redirect back will go to view 2
     - if it succeded, should redirect to view 3

GET  - show view 3 (order confirmation)
```

Your problem will disappear with this route structure

Comment: This is flow that I have but I want to keep everything under the same url. But when a validation error occurs I return to the shopping cart instead of the payment method in  your example.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue, if you want to keep everything under the same url you can't redirect back, because you're trying to have a `fake back`. Don't know how to explain it. Maybe you should just return the view again

Comment: Didn't think of returning the view! thanks, I did `return view('/pages/test2')->withInput($request)->withErrors(["my error"]);` and that worked.

Comment: You said `You shouldn't be using return view() inside a post request.` why not? how would I display a view ?

Comment: A post request should redirect to a GET route after performing their business logic. At least that's how I always do and never had a problem. You can't access a view from a POST route without submitting a form